# Filter navigation subform using combobox in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a navigation subform that I am trying to filter using a combobox.

The combobox is based on a query that lists the possible options of the field that I am trying to filter.

I have used the code below and have gotten an error message that says

> The record source ... specified on this form or report does not exist.

Code:

```vb
Forms!frmMainMenu!NavigationSubform.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Records WHERE [INVESTOR_NAME] = '" & Me.ComboInvestors & "'"
```

I have also tried

```vb
Forms!frmMainMenu!NavigationSubform.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Records WHERE [INVESTOR_NAME] =" & Me.ComboInvestors
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apologies for the layout but my code edits do not seem to be working despite looking correct in edit mode.

Comment: Is `Records` really the name of the table/query you want to read the data from?

Comment: That was it - I updated it with the query name.  Thanks!

Comment: try: Forms!frmMainMenu.NavigationSubform.Form.RecordSource = ....